# mod_rewrite to redirect URL with query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

I have a lot of working mod_rewrite rules already in my `httpd.conf` file.  I just recently found that Google had indexed one of my non-rewritten URLs with a query string in it:

`http://example.com/?state=arizona`

I would like to use mod_rewrite to do a 301 redirect to this URL:

`http://example.com/arizona`

The issue is that later on in my rewrite rules, that 2nd URL is being rewritten to pass query variables on to WordPress.  It ends up getting rewritten to:

`http://example.com/index.php?state=arizona`

Which is the proper functionality.  Everything I have tried so far has either not worked at all or put me in an endless rewrite loop.  This is what I have right now, which is getting stuck in a loop:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=arizona [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://example.com/arizona [R=301,L]
#older rewrite rule that passes query string based on URL:
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)$ index.php?state=$1 [L]
```

which gives me an endless rewrite loop and takes me to this URL:
`http://example.com/arizona?state=arizona`

I then tried this:

```
RewriteRule .*   http://example.com/arizona? [R=301,L]
```

which got rid of the query string in the URL, but still creates a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, adding the 2nd RewriteCond finally fixed it - now rewriting correctly and no loop:

```
# redirect dynamic URL: ?state=arizona
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=arizona [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://domain.com/arizona? [R=301,L]
# older rewrite rule that passes query string based on URL:
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)$ index.php?state=$1 [L]
```

And here's the code to make it work for any state value, not just arizona:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([A-Za-z-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://domain.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\?state=arizona$ [NC]`

should be

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=arizona [NC]`

The request_uri ends at the ? token.

Comment: You probably need to tighten up `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?state=$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)$ index.php?state=$1 [L]`. index.php won't match that and won't get redirected.

Comment: how would the "dot" character match the character class [\w-] ?  Anyway, i changed it above, but still have the same loop.